Getting authentication error while connecting Laravel application to QuickBooks web connector
I am trying to connect Laravel appliaciton to the web connector, but I am getting an authentication error
Although Laravel logs says authentication is successful but web connector shows the following error
20240719.22:00:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20240719.22:00:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: Your Laravel App Name
20240719.22:00:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): Your Laravel App Name
20240719.22:00:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: https://clients-ama.test/quickbooks
20240719.22:00:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20240719.22:00:42 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Received from serverVersion() following parameter:<serverVersionRet="">
20240719.22:00:42 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application sent a null for server version. Allowing update operation.
20240719.22:00:42 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="34.0.1001.27">
20240719.22:00:45 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : Received from clientVersion() following parameter:<clientVersionRet="">
20240719.22:00:45 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application agrees with the current version of QBWebConnector. Allowing update operation.
20240719.22:00:45 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'Your Laravel App Name', username = 'admin'
20240719.22:00:45 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="admin"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20240719.22:00:48 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
More info:
StackTrace =    at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = QBWebConnector
20240719.22:00:48 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20240719.22:00:48 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20240719.22:00:48 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdate() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
20240719.22:00:48 UTC   : UpdateThisScheduledApp() : QBWC1031: Update completed with some error. Application has been notified of the error accordingly. See QWCLog for further information.


Following is my handler method, which is called by route in web.php
public function handleRequest(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info('QuickBooks request received', [
            'content' => $request->getContent(),
            'headers' => $request->headers->all()
        ]);
    
        $server = new SoapServer(public_path('QuickBooks.wsdl'), [
            'uri' => 'http://developer.intuit.com/',
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
        ]);
    
        $server->setClass(QuickBooksService::class);
    
        ob_start();
        try {
            $server->handle();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('SOAP Error: ' . $e->getMessage(), [
                'exception' => $e,
                'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString(),
                'request' => $request->getContent()
            ]);
            $fault = new \SoapFault('Server', $e->getMessage());
            $server->fault($fault->faultcode, $fault->faultstring);
        }
        $response = ob_get_clean();
    
        Log::info('QuickBooks response sent', ['content' => $response]);
    
        return response($response, 200, [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        ]);
    }

Following is my authenticate method in Laravel
public function authenticate($strUserName, $strPassword)
    {
        Log::info("authenticate called with username: $strUserName");
        if ($strUserName === 'mendy' && $strPassword === 'password') {
            $ticket = md5(uniqid());
            $companyFile = '';
            $waitTime = 0;
            $minVersion = '';  // or specify a minimum version if needed
            $responseArray = [$ticket, $companyFile, $waitTime, $minVersion];
            $responseString = implode('|', $responseArray);
            Log::info("Authentication successful. Returning: $responseString");
            return $responseString;
        } else {
            Log::warning("Authentication failed for username: $strUserName");
            return 'nvu';
        }
    }


Your question is missing the log output. Locate the file in the diagnostic messages, open it, clean it from confidential information (if any) and [edit] the contents into your question. Without that information your question does not look very specific. This is in reference to "Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details."

@hakre I don't know why I see this message to check QWCLog.txt, as the above logs are from the same file

Hmm, perhaps I misread it then because of that. You could make visible that the first log is from that file, e.g. put the filename in front, this likely would have helped me to spot that earlier. For the actual problem, consult your vendors support for the concrete error messages and codes and trouble-shoot the issue with them, I don't understand those messages and they seem related to that product.

@hakre I came here because I thought most of the people would have already connected to Web connector and the issue may they have seen before as well
I don't know what I am doing wrong

From the error message it sounds like a problem with the library henceforth likely a support issue with your software vendor, but I'm also only guessing. Honestly, contact support, that's what it is for.

@hakre Thank you mate, I did contacted QuickBooks support but they said they don't provide support for the integrations

Perhaps they are not the vendor of that package? Which package are you using? This is a relevant detail you should [edit] into your question, also normally a link does not hurt.

@hakre I don't know what you mean be package but I am using Laravel version 11 and to SOAP for the connection I am using this package "artisaninweb/laravel-soap": "0.3.0.10",

Yes such kind of package, just for the Quickbooks integration..
